# Is it possible to run Silverlight 5 on 1and1.com hosting?

Tags: hosting, silverlight-5.0

Is it possible to run Silverlight 5 application on 1and1.com hosting ?

After deploying the files and after browsing in place of the silverlight application I got the  button "Get XML".

What I am doing wrong ?

According to http://faq.1and1.com/scripting_languages_supported/webconfig/2008/4.html the .xap is supported.

Comment: I don't see anything else than the XAP association to do... so it should work yes. Could you link to the page you're trying?

Answer (score 0):

After contacting the support it turned out that I had the old Windows Hosting with Silverlight disabled.

After enabling it my application started without problems.

So yes. Silverlight 5 works only if you have Silverlight 5 plugin installed on your machine.
It seems that depends on the ability to download the .xap  and to initialize the Silverlight object.